# NoMethodError at /line_items undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass, simple model attribute unrecognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, associations, models, attr

I cannot access an associated model from another model while defining a method. I get the following error when trying to access an objects attibute (size's 'price' attribute) while in an associated object (line_item). Below is my code and errors:

### models

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :quantity, :unit_price, :product, :cart, :color_id, :size_id, :extra_id, :color, :size, :extra
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
  has_one :color
  has_one :size
  has_one :extra
  validates :quantity, :presence => true
  def item_price
    if size.price.nil? || size.price == 0
      if  extra.price.nil? || extra.price ==0
        product.price
      else
        product.price + extra.price
      end
    else
      if extra.price.nil? || extra.price == 0
        product.price + size.price
      else
        product.price + size.price + extra.price
      end
    end
  end
  def full_price
          unit_price * quantity
  end
end


class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :name, :price, :product_id, :line_item_id
        belongs_to :product
        belongs_to :line_item
  def size_display
    "#{name} +#{price}"
  end
end
```

### controller

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end
  def create
    @line_item = LineItem.create!(params[:line_item].merge(:cart => current_cart))
    @line_item.update_attributes!(:unit_price => @line_item.item_price)
    redirect_to current_cart_url
  end
end
```

### error

```
NoMethodError at /line_items
undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass

LineItem#item_price
app/models/line_item.rb, line 10
LineItemsController#create
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb, line 7
```

Any insight appreciated.

### Update

My size object doesn't seem to be nil through analyzing my request parameters, what could be causing this?

## Update No. 2

### good debug info found from console:

```
1.9.3-p125 :008 > debugAttempt = LineItem.first
  LineItem Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" LIMIT 1
 => #<LineItem id: 1, unit_price: nil, product_id: 1, cart_id: 1, color_id: 1, size_id: 2, extra_id: nil, quantity: 2, created_at: "2013-06-25 03:41:27", updated_at: "2013-06-25 03:41:27"> 
1.9.3-p125 :009 > debugAttempt.size
  Size Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."line_item_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 => nil 
1.9.3-p125 :010 > debugAttempt.size_id
 => 2 
1.9.3-p125 :015 > Size.find(debugAttempt.size_id).price.round
  Size Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => 50
```

so basically size isn't nil but rather i can't find access the associated size object from the lineItem object. i can only access size_id.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You have a `LineItem` that doesn't have a `size`.

Comment: But do you only have one LineItem? Did it get created from those parameters? I'd recommend making `size_id` a NOT NULL column in the database and adding appropriate validations (yes, do both).

Comment: It was created by those parameters, I have objects which don't have sizes so i need size to be null at times. Does that smell bad?

Comment: Do you have a Size with and `id` of 2? It smells bad if your LineItem is going to assume that `size` won't be `nil`; you'll probably have similar problems with `extra`.

Comment: Yes I do, I'm protecting the `nil` cases with conditionals. I'm going to change `extra` in the same manner as `size` when I debug this `NoMethodError`

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why `size` is `nil`, could it be my association syntax? my form seems correct, using `collection_select`...

Comment: I think your [`has_one`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association) is backwards, try reversing the `has_one` and `belongs_to`. I'll spare you a rant about how badly they screwed up some of the association names since you probably have your rant about that now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `LineItem` has_one `Size`, foreign key should be in your `sizes` table. So you should rather debug with `Size.find_by_line_item_id(debugAttempt.id)` and if the result is `nil`, the associated record simply doesn't exist in db.